# Google Batch API no longer accepts our requests

Tags: google-api

Our test suite is currently failing on tests that use the google batch API for the google drive API. They used to work and we can not find any documented changes to either API.

The request is as follows (copied from chromium developer tools):

```
:authority: www.googleapis.com
:method: POST
:path: /batch/drive/v3?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
:scheme: https
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Length: 2740
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
Origin: https://OUR.LOCAL.TESTDOMAIN:PORT
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="115", "Not/A)Brand";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data: CMbaygE=
   Decoded:
   message ClientVariations {
     // Active client experiment variation IDs.
     repeated int32 variation_id = [3321158];
   }
```

with the following body

```
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-1>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-2>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-3>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-4>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-5>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-6>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f--
```

and our file ids and API key being replaced by <FILE_ID-X> and <GDRIVE_API_KEY> respectively.

We receive the following response from Google's servers:

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (121 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (121 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, turns out the API disliked the double newline between the headers and the method (verb) of the single requests. if I remove one of them it works again, i.e.

```
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/http

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID-3>?key=<GDRIVE_API_KEY>
--eeedd3d5-cd3e-4d26-91e7-f6823904fe5f
```

no idea why this behaviour changed but apparently now only one newline is allowed.

as a side note: this request will work also without the headers (and to be honest I think we are using the wrong ones but for now that wasn't the problem)